# How to change the Caps Lock key to Backspace on the external keyboard I am using with my iPad?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, keybindings

I reckon there are programs on Mac or PC that could do the trick but I haven't been able to find an app that would let me just remap this one key. My keyboard does not come with any software that would do such a remapping either.

Can someone please provide some solutions or guidance?

Answer (score -1):

As you are using **iPad** so I am sharing a link which will definitely work for you because the ability to remap keys on your keyboard may not seem like a really big deal, but it’s the fact that Apple made it possible is what makes things so exciting. After seemingly ignoring it other than hardware releases, Apple seems laser-focused on creating something we haven’t seen yet with the iPad.

https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-remap-caps-lock-keyboard-button-on-ipados/

Comment: But that doesn't let you remap capslock to backspace.  Only to control, option, command, escape,  globe, or nothing.  So it will not work for what the question is asking.

Comment: Also, if you are going to post a link [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.